# Read data from Singapore MRT card - Android NfcB

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to read values from ez-link Singapore MRT card.

The image below is my current output:

[image: current output]

How to fetch values like travel history / current balance, like in this image:

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 0):

The data presented from your NFC scan is just a reference to an account stored by Singapore MRT. It doesn't look like there is any way to interface with those accounts (understandably), you cannot get the information you are after from the card.

Comment: There are plenty of apps available in the playstore which reads from MRT cards. Displays balance amount and history. Just curious to know how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ezlink is proprietary interface, you prolly need to subscribe and pay for API in order to interpret the information read from ezlink via NFC